# Unable insert data to table beacuse of Trigger in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I created a table `ebill(name varchar, prev int, curr int)`. There is a trigger that raises an exception when values with `prevreading = currreading` are entered. But it does not take other data also.

```
-- This is my function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BILL_CHECK() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$ 
BEGIN
 IF (NEW.PREVREADING=NEW.CURRREADING) THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Data Entry Error';
 END IF;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

--This is my trigger
CREATE TRIGGER BILL                                          
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EBILL
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE BILL_CHECK();

INSERT INTO EBILL VALUES('MELVY',7,7);-- Raises Exception. Working.

NSERT INTO EBILL VALUES('MELVY',7,8);-- No change in the table.insert 00
INSERT 0 0
```

Why can't I insert the second group pf data?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you return `NULL`.

This is a signal to abort the data modification.

You should

```
RETURN NEW;
```